# How to do a set of kets in LaTeX?

Tags: braket

I would like to define a set of kets, in a way that the brackets that define the set scale with the content inside. I don't know how to do it, because I usually use the `\Set` command, but this gives an error if there is also a ket inside the set. Here's a code that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
% This works, but the brakets don't scale with the contents inside.
\{ \ket{x} \in \mathcal{H} | \ket{x} = \sum_i c_i \ket{e_i} \}
% The following doesn't work:
%\Set{\ket{x}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Here's the error: `! Missing } inserted.`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For scaling the braces, use `\left\{` and `\right\}`

Comment: Off topic:  `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so there's no need to load it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `braket.sty` we find

```
\def\bra#1{\mathinner{\langle{#1}|}}
\def\ket#1{\mathinner{|{#1}\rangle}}
\def\braket#1{\mathinner{\langle{#1}\rangle}}
\def\Bra#1{\left\langle#1\right|}
\def\Ket#1{\left|#1\right\rangle}
```

and in the `\Set` macro, `|` is made active. I don't fully understand why `\Set{\bra{x}}` and `\Set{\ket{x}}` produce errors while `\Set{\Bra{x}}` etc. do not, but a simple way to fix this is to redefine `\bra` and `\ket` using the otherwise equivalent `\vert` instead of `|`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{braket}

\renewcommand\bra[1]{\mathinner{\langle{#1}\vert}}
\renewcommand\ket[1]{\mathinner{\vert{#1}\rangle}}
\renewcommand\Bra[1]{\left\langle#1\right\vert}
\renewcommand\Ket[1]{\left\vert#1\right\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Set{ \ket{x} \in \mathcal{H} | \ket{x} = \sum_i c_i \ket{e_i} }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: "`|` is made active" is not really the correct statement, the correct statement is its mathcode is set to `"8000` i.e. it's *math-active*. That way, it works even if the `|` is already tokenized.

Comment: You should also update the definitions of `\Bra` and `\Ket`.

Comment: @egreg Added to the answer

Comment: @user202729 Another answer explaining what's really happening would be useful. For example, I don't understand why `\Set{{|}}` errors

Comment: @mbert It fails because `|` is at the wrong group level. It's essentially like `{\left(}\right)`

Answer (score 5):

The answer doesn't mention exactly what the error message "missing }" does mean here. Let me explain this.

TeX primitive `\middle` must be used only at the same group level as a group bounded by `\left` and `\right`. So

```
$$ \left\{ xxx \middle| yyy \right\} $$
```

is correct usage of `\middle` but

```
$$ \left\{ {xxx \middle| yyy} \right\} $$
```

is incorrect and the `\middle` command reports "missing } inserted" and "\middle read again". Of course, if we accept inserting `}` here then we get next error "Extra }, or forgotten \right" when `yyy}` is processed.

The `\Set{abc|def}` expands (roughly speaking) to

```
\left\{ {abc}\middle|{def}} \right\},
```

because the `|` is set as math active character (locally, in the first inner group). It expands to `}\middle|{`. This is correct usage of `\middle`: at the same group level as the outer group. But `\ket{zzz}` is defined as

```
\mathinner{|zzz}
```

and because `\Set` sets `|` as math active character, then `\Set{\ker{zzz}}` expands to

```
\left\{ {\mathinner{ }\middle|{zzz}} \right\}
```

Now, the `\middle` is used at bad level of group.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation!